# Uniformly distributed points distance question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, combinatorial-geometry

> $N$ points are placed randomly according to a uniform distribution in a $1 \times 1$ square. If $M$ is the number of points that have a distance more than $c/\sqrt{N}$ to others, then prove $\exists c,\alpha>0$ such that
>   $$\lim\limits_{N\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(M>\alpha N)=1$$

Besides this question, please let me know if you can find the average of $M$.

This is follow up question for [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2250228/probability-that-points-uniformly-distributed-are-at-least-c-sqrtn-far-apar)

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_i$ be the indicator variable of the event that the $i$-th point "is free", i.e., it has a distance more than $c/\sqrt{N}$ to all others.

Then, assuming $N$ is large and we ignore "border effects" (points near the border of the square),

$$P(X_i=1)=E(X_i)= 1- \pi \frac{c^2}{N}$$

Then the expected number of total "free" points is

$$E(Y)=\sum_i E(X_i)= N -\pi c^2$$

Update: This answer was writen before the OP edited the question: This is useless now

Comment: Thanks so much. I changed the problem a little bit. Sorry.

Comment: I changed the problem again to cover your answer. I'd appreciate it if you could also answer my updated question.

Comment: I can change it back to the original question if you want.